# Eclipse project disappearance and An internal error occurred during: "Launching ...". java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: eclipse, cocos2d-x

I installed cocos2d-x version 3.2 and eclipse juno 23.After that I configured eclipse for cocos and c++ development and build the project.I closed eclipse and opened it again but when did that my projects gone and java null pointer error shows up.My root project exist but when I expand it nothing exist into sub project folder and the project exist entirly on hard drive.

What did I do for fixing:

- reimport project:again root project exist and there is no sub folder.
- delete project and create new one:works fine but when reset eclipse again shows error.In other word refer to first line of my question.

This is image of eclipse environment:
http://speedy.sh/xu2h8/Untitled.png

And this is log:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.8.0_05
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-07-23 12:50:35.970
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-07-23 12:50:43.927
!MESSAGE Warning: EGit couldn't detect the installation path "gitPrefix" of native Git. Hence EGit can't respect system level
Git settings which might be configured in ${gitPrefix}/etc/gitconfig under the native Git installation directory.
The most important of these settings is core.autocrlf. Git for Windows by default sets this parameter to true in
this system level configuration. The Git installation location can be configured on the
Team > Git > Configuration preference page's 'System Settings' tab.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.egit.ui 2 0 2014-07-23 12:50:43.931
!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories: 'C:\Users\ABBAS-PC'. If this is
not correct please set the HOME environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows and
EGit might behave differently since they see different configuration options.
This warning can be switched off on the Team > Git > Confirmations and Warnings preference page.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2014-07-23 12:50:47.858
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.loadData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescription.loadDatas(CProjectDescription.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.loadProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.getProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescriptionInternal(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ManagedBuildManager.findBuildInfo(ManagedBuildManager.java:2709)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ManagedBuildManager.getBuildInfo(ManagedBuildManager.java:2970)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ManagedBuildManager.getBuildInfo(ManagedBuildManager.java:2925)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ResourceChangeHandler2$Visitor.visit(ResourceChangeHandler2.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.ResourceDelta.accept(ResourceDelta.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.ResourceChangeHandler2.resourceChanged(ResourceChangeHandler2.java:179)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1530)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2353)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:793)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.core.JavaCore.setClasspathContainer(JavaCore.java:5269)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer.updateProjects(AndroidClasspathContainerInitializer.java:143)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.updateProjects(ProjectHelper.java:276)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin$7.run(AdtPlugin.java:1451)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.cdt.core 4 0 2014-07-23 12:50:53.111
!MESSAGE Error
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.loadData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescription.loadDatas(CProjectDescription.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.loadProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.getProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescriptionInternal(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.computeSourceRoots(CProject.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.computeChildren(CProject.java:624)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.buildStructure(CProject.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.openWhenClosed(CElement.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.getElementInfo(CElement.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.getElementInfo(CElement.java:297)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.Parent.getChildren(Parent.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.create(CModelManager.java:280)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.create(CModelManager.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.createElement(DeltaProcessor.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.traverseDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.traverseDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.processResourceDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.resourceChanged(CModelManager.java:886)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1530)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui.workbench 4 2 2014-07-23 12:55:03.534
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.ui.workbench".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.loadData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescription.loadDatas(CProjectDescription.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.loadProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.getProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescriptionInternal(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ExcludedFileDecorator.decorate(ExcludedFileDecorator.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.decorate(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager$LightweightRunnable.run(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.decorate(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.getDecorations(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.ensureResultCached(DecorationScheduler.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.run(DecorationScheduler.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-07-23 12:55:03.547
!MESSAGE Exception in Decorator. The 'C/C++ Files and Folders Excluded from Build' decorator will be disabled.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2014-07-23 12:55:03.550
!MESSAGE java.lang.NullPointerException
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.loadData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescription.loadDatas(CProjectDescription.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.loadProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:486)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.getProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:231)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescriptionInternal(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:398)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.ui.viewsupport.ExcludedFileDecorator.decorate(ExcludedFileDecorator.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorDefinition.decorate(LightweightDecoratorDefinition.java:263)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager$LightweightRunnable.run(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.decorate(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.LightweightDecoratorManager.getDecorations(LightweightDecoratorManager.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.ensureResultCached(DecorationScheduler.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.decorators.DecorationScheduler$1.run(DecorationScheduler.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2014-07-23 13:02:27.459
!MESSAGE Invalid property category path: ValidationPropertiesPage (bundle: org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui, propertyPage: org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.propertyPage.project.validation)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this Error, 
Possible Cause:-

Its a Linking Error occurred when i try to link Resources folder into my Eclipse Project explorer, when you link a folder into your project the .cproject file within the proj.android folder got modified. There are two < CConfiguration > sections in this file. When editing the c++ include paths in eclipse, only one of them is modified. This inconsistency cause the cdt crash.

Solution:

In fact there should only be one < CConfiguration >, so delete the second one, it start from line 85. After that you can edit c++ include paths in eclipse and no crash will happen.

If this workout didn't work with you then avoid linking folders to your project @ all cost. 
Hope this Helps You